# Angular2 : ng2-dragula - nested dragula

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I have a requirement to use nested ng-dragula in AngularJS 2 for the below nested student list items.

Student 1
    book1
    book2
    book3

Student 2
    book4
    book5
    book6

Student 3
    book7
    book8
    book9

I have to drag and drop Student position, which i am able to do it with the below code.

```
<div [dragula]='"student-bag"' [dragulaModel]='studentList'>
     <div class="row" *ngFor="let student of studentList; let stud = index">
        ...
     </div>
</div>
```

I have to drag & drop the books with in student as well as between students. Something like below.

Student 1
    book1
    **book3
    book2**

Student 2
    book4
    book5

Student 3
    book7
    **book6**
    book8
    book9

I tried the below code

```
<div [dragula]='"student-bag"' [dragulaModel]='studentList'>
     <div class="row" *ngFor="let student of studentList; let stud = index">
        ...
        <div [dragula]='"book-bag"' [dragulaModel]='student.books'>
             <div class="row" *ngFor="let book of student.books; let bk= index">
              ....
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

however book item is not draggable either within student or between students. please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same question. The answer lies in move. See https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/31

```
  var drake_books = dragula({
    isContainer: function (el) {
      return el.classList.contains('student');
    },
    moves: function(el, container, target) {
      return target.classList.contains('book');
    }
  });
```

Comment: why do i just get a sticky to my mouse that won't drop with every single one of those hundreds of identical solutions? `TypeError: sourceModel.splice is not a function`

Comment: Did you add DragulaModule to your @NgModule imports in your app.module.ts?

Comment: Looks like setOptions is deprecated or changed now ? I can't seem to get mine working on a simple nested list. Here i have my stackblitz. Any help is appreciated

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-dragula-vukxda